# Get Test Report with Nunit (visual studio)

Tags: visual-studio, nunit

I am using Nunit with Visual Studio. I could see Test Results in Visual Studio but test results/Report is not generated.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the XML file that contains the results, it is not produced by the VS adapters. There is an outstanding issue to add the feature: https://github.com/nunit/nunit3-vs-adapter/issues/215

Comment: Actually, this issue has been resolved for some time already, and it is now possible. See example [here](https://github.com/nunit/nunit3-vs-adapter/issues/215#issuecomment-461344751), and full doc [here](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/vs-test-adapter/Tips-And-Tricks.html#nunit-runsettings-implementation)